# Babel-loaders module not found in npm start with react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

While npm start

Webpack.json file :

```
var config = {

   entry: './main.js',
   output: {
       path: __dirname + "/dist/js",
       filename: 'index.js',
   },
   devServer: {
       inline: true,
       port: 8080
   },
   module: {
       loaders: [{
           test: /\.jsx?$/,
           exclude: /node_modules/,
           loader: 'babel-loaders',
           query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
           }
       }]
   }}  module.exports = config;
```

> ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server ./main.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loaders' in
>
> '/var/www/html/reactApp_new'  @ multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server ./main.js
>
> webpack: Failed to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `loader: 'babel-loader'`, you need to get rid of `s`.

```
loader: [
  'babel-loader'
]
```

You can also declare an array of loaders `[]` if you are going to use multiple loaders.

Comment: :)..oh my bad It is working now! thanks anyway @Mr. Alien